# Failed to get exact time with uib-timepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using uib-timepicker.I selected time and while i'm trying to send the data,uib-timepicker converts to 5:30min less than the time I have given. You can understand clearly when you see the screenshot  I have shared..!

```html
<html>
<div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
  <uib-timepicker ng-model="atSettings.attendanceSettings.signIn" hour-step="1" minute-step="15" show-meridian="atSettings.ismeridian">
  </uib-timepicker>
  <uib-timepicker ng-model="atSettings.attendanceSettings.signOut" hour-step="1" minute-step="15" show-meridian="atSettings.ismeridian">
  </uib-timepicker>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button type="submit" ng-click="atSettings.save()" class="btncontinue">Send</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>

</html>
```

[uib-timepicker screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Tib.png)

angularjs:

```js
angular.module('picassoApp')
  .controller('settingsDisplayController', ['$state',
    function($state) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.ismeridian = true;
      vm.save = function() {
        var psignIn = new Date(vm.attendanceSettings.signIn).toISOString();
        var psignOut = new Date(vm.attendanceSettings.signOut).toISOString();
        vm.postSettings = {
          sigIn: psignIn,
          signOut: psignOut
        };
        console.log(vm.postSettings);
      };

    }
  ]);
```

Thanks advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use uib-timepicker everywhere in your project you will not get any problem with this. Because it stores time 5 hrs 30 min less than you have given and If you try to fetch from db and show it in uib-timepicker it shows the correct time as you gave.uib-timepicker automatically converts time as ISO String while displaying.

Comment: Yep.. your r8..Great Answer.. Thanks